# Loading an ONNX Model into OpenCV (converted from Pytorch)

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, onnx

I tried loading an ONNX model (can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kJJDDHgDe2VK4lNNGBbs9K7st8XYxOjp/view?usp=share_link)) into OpenCV. The ONNX model was converted from a Pytorch model (can be found [here](https://github.com/huangyangyu/ADNet)).
I load it in OpenCV 4.7.0 with:

```
import cv2
cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('model.onnx')
```

But when I try to load it, this error appears:

> error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\bld\libopencv_1675730119851\work\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:1073: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::ONNXImporter::handleNode'
>
> > Node [ReduceMax@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!/pre/pre.0/addcoords/ReduceMax) parse error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\bld\libopencv_1675730119851\work\modules\dnn\src\layers\reduce_layer.cpp:336: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() > 0 in function 'cv::dnn::ReduceLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'

It runs perfectly with onnxruntime:

```
import onnxruntime as rt
import numpy as np
onnxnet = rt.InferenceSession('model.onnx')
input_name = onnxnet.get_inputs()[0].name
input_tensor = np.random.rand(1,3,256,256).astype(np.float32)
output = onnxnet.run([], {input_name: input_tensor})
```

Why doesn't it work in OpenCV and is there any way to make it work?

Comment: It is probably model.onnx input shape is dynamic. Opencv currently does not support dynamic input. You can change model input to static.

Comment: @ikibir The input shape is already static.

Comment: your model's input size is (batch_size,3,256,256). batch_size should be a static number